# Can I install Fallout 3 GOTY DLC to a USB drive?

Tags: xbox-360, fallout-3

I bought Fallout 3 GOTY and I unfortunately have the 4GB Xbox 360 without a hard drive. So what I thought might work is this: I take a USB and my game to a friends house who has a hard drive. So I install the DLC onto his hard drive. When that is done, I transfer the DLC to my USB.

I then take my stuff back home and plug my USB into the Xbox. I load up the game and select my USB with the DLC on it (I also put my last save onto my USB so I wouldn't have to start over) and the game says something like Loading extra content. So I think it works but when you go into my game I walk around for a while and I get no new radio stations or any notifications. Did my method work or do I just need to walk around more?

Answer (score 2):

It didn't work unfortunately, because the DLC was *installed* on your friends hard drive, while you only have the files. You will need to *install* it on your own xbox, (I don't know how much space it will take up)

Comment: Redownload it if it's a code. If it's a disk DLC install, it will install again. If it has to be on the HDD to install, get your mate to bring his HDD over and try installing to that. If it's downloadable DLC you just have to redownload it, basically just be online.